# How to get the checkout object in Woocommerce custom template

Tags: php, wordpress, object, woocommerce, methods

For WooCommerce I create an own checkout page but I have an Issue.

The code `$checkout->get_value( 'billing_first_name' );` does not work in my template file.

My file is called with `get_template_part( 'temp-parts/content/pages/checkout-billing'); in the file **woocommerce/checkout/form-billing.php**

This generate an error

> Call to a member function get_value() on null

If I use this code directly in the file woocommerce/checkout/form-billing.php the code does work.

Is it possible to get the checkout information in my own template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `$checkout` variable is not defined, you should use instead:

```
WC()->checkout->get_value( 'billing_first_name' );
```

Now it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `global $woocommerce` and after that `$woocommerce->checkout->get_value( 'billing_first_name' );`